# What is the variable live_site in configuration.php for?

Tags: security, configuration

The advice for the value of $live_site in configuration.php is often in Joomla forum an empty string represented by two single quotation marks. For example here: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=811&t=998357

I am not very familiar with server configuration. What exactly does the following warning mean and is it still up to date?

> "Running on a non-vhost environment:
> When you are running Joomla on a non-vhost environment please make sure that you set the live_site setting within the configruation.php to your domain in order to protect you against potential Host Header Injection. All sites that are running within an vhost setup are not affected by this issue." https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/Joomla!_Setup#Running_on_a_non-vhost_environment

If I see it correctly, this is the relevant place in the Joomla-code.
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/b38856dfec12c0755084e10b66579f18abf4cc6b/libraries/src/Uri/Uri.php#L134

**Addition on 26.12**
Why is it recommended to leave the variable empty? In my opinion there is no reason for this and the correct specification should always be better? Of course, you have to remember to change this variable when you move. For example, if you are developing under a different URI.
Because with  the correct specification of $live_site the URI for creating the relative Routes in Joomla is read from the configuration and not from the HTTP header and therefore an [HTTP host header attack](https://crashtest-security.com/invalid-host-header/#how-to-prevent-host-header-attacks) is more difficult.

Am I seeing this wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

TL:DR - I don't think there is much use of the $live_site parameter and probably even less use of non-vhost environments so it may be still relevant for some obscure set up but I don't think anyone is going to miss it if the sentence was removed.

I have used $live_site since Joomla 1 when I have wanted to put the Joomla installation for the primary domain of the cPanel account into a sub directory and hide the sub-directory from appearing in the URL. I use it as part of a hack to get around a limitation of cPanel.

For the Primary Domain cpanel expects it to be in the public_html folder, /root. If you installed Joomla into a sub-directory, e.g. /fred, then the URL would look like this.

```
www.mydomain.com./fred/mypage
```

With a couple of lines of .htacces magic and putting `$live_site="https://mydomain.com";` in the configuration.php my URL would look like this

```
www.mydoamin.com/mypage
```

Appearing like any other add-on domain used on the cPanel account, hiding the sub-directory from the public.

Some people will say very strongly that $live_site should not be used but provide no reasons to support their view and I have not seen any other uses of $live_site over the years but there is no mention of it being depreciated that I have come across either.

However in Joomla 4 a change was introduced that breaks the Logout processing of a site using $live_site, returning a HTML 404, that as far as I am aware still exists. I haven't tested it in Joomla 5 yet and I am possibly the only person that has noticed it is now broken which I think supports my view that it isn't widely used.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I asked my question more specifically above. I was primarily interested in finding out why the variable should be left empty. In my eyes there is no reason for this and the correct specification should always be better?

Comment: I would suggest `$live_site` was originally added as an option to deal with a specific situation a long time ago and therefore the default behaviour expects the property to be empty. I did a quick test and removed `$live_site` from my `configuration.php` and some basic page loads didn't show any adverse affects. It maybe a question that needs to be asked of the Joomla Security team to clarify if a HTTP Header attack is still possible with modern versions of Joomla. My reading of the links you provide and the code suggest it is not, maybe no `$live_site` property should be the default position.